# flattening this array stack PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sha1

I'm trying to find a way to flatten this array

I'm outputting a sha1 conversion
but I wish to break it into 4 parts of 10

then change its order before saving it.

here is my code so far.

```js
<?php

$hash = bin2hex(random_bytes(5));
$randomhash = sha1($hash);
$parts = str_split($randomhash, 10);
$newar = $parts[3].$parts.[1].$parts.[2].$parts[0];
$hashflat = implode(" ",$newar);

echo $hashflat;
```

However, this does not work as desired.
Is there a simple way to implode

```
$parts[3] $parts [1] $parts [2] $parts[0]
```

in this order to a flat output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$newar` will already be as you want it, assuming you want it as a string.

However, you want spaces so it'll be:

```
$hash = bin2hex(random_bytes(5));
$randomhash = sha1($hash);
$parts = str_split($randomhash, 10);
$newar = $parts[3]." ".$parts[1]." ".$parts[2]." ".$parts[0];
```

this will return it as a string with spaces rather than an array. if you want it as a reordered array it's

```
$hash = bin2hex(random_bytes(5));
$randomhash = sha1($hash);
$parts = str_split($randomhash, 10);
$newar = array($parts[3],$parts[1],$parts[2],$parts[0]);
```

Comment: that results in this error

`FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected '$parts' (T_VARIABLE) on line number 6`

Answer (score 0):

```
$newar = array($parts[3],$parts[1],$parts[2],$parts[0]);
```

setting a new array seemed to work in this case for me.

not sure if this is the correct way of doing things though.